# How does 'parseInt(String, radix)' work?

Tags: java, parseint

I understand that the `parseInt` method is used to convert strings to int, but I do not know how. I understand that if you say:

```
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("52", 10));
```

will give you 52 in base 10. What I am unaware of is if you say replace base 10 with 15, how does it exactly compute. From some research, I found people saying that you must use ASCII values. If it helps, I am trying to be able to solve this on paper solely, without the work of any more code.

Comment: did you have a look at the implementation? http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.parseInt%28java.lang.String%2Cint%29

Comment: @SagarV You could also have retag it as JavaScript and save 30 seconds for other SO users instead of waitting Jens to do it.

Comment: Please read [Base of the numeral system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation#Base_of_the_numeral_system) theory. I suspect your question not about code but about mathemathics

Answer (score 7):

You're right that the number denotes the base. You are not right that

> `Integer.parseInt("52", 10)` will give you 52 in base 10.

This will in fact parse the number 52 *as if it were* in base 10. 52 could be base 6 for all we know.

For example:

```
Integer.parseInt("101", 2);
```

Is saying parse the binary (base 2) number one-zero-one. It is *not* saying parse one hundred and one into binary. This will return the base 10 number 5.

Any number which is returned is a standard integer which if you try to print it will be in base 10.

---

Worth noting that if you try and parse a number which can not possibly exist in that base, for example:

```
Integer.parseInt("599", 2);
```

then you will get an exception.

Answer (score 5):

The string you are parsing could be in a specific base which you supply with the radix command to parse to an int.  The int is a numerical value and doesn't have a specific base per se.

Examples

```
Integer.parseInt("52", 10) returns 52
Integer.parseInt("52", 8) returns the numerical value 42 (8*5+2)
Integer.parseInt("A2", 16) returns the base 10 value 162
```

Comment: Integer.parseInt("52", 15) returns the numerical value 77 (15*5+2)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

`parseInt(String s, int radix)` methods works like so:

1. The `radix` parameter is checked. It should be in the
   range 2 - 36
2. Each character of the string is parsed and verified to be a valid digit (within the bound defined by the radix)
3. The result is multiplied for the `radix` and incrementally added to a results variable
4. The results variable is returned

The algorithm is quite simple. An important piece of the work is done by the part that verifies whether the digit is valid.

Around this code there are a few checks that will eventually cause a `NumberFormatException`, e.g. the presence of valid signs (`+` or `-`) before the digit, the presence of leading zeros, overflows, etc.

Comment: @Michael thanks for improving my answer :)